# Converting a string to list of Objects in java

Tags: java

I have this string:

```js
[{
        "expectedInput": "hello",
        "expectedResponse": "how can i help you?"
    },
    {
        "expectedInput": "need sip support",
        "expectedResponse": "ok, let me check "
    }
]
```

and i want to convert into List of Objects i.e `List<MessageDetails>`
where `MessageDetails.class` is

```
public class MessageDetails {

    private String expectedInput;
    private String expectedResponse;
    public String getExpectedInput() {
        return expectedInput;
    }
    public void setExpectedInput(String expectedInput) {
        this.expectedInput = expectedInput;
    }
    public String getExpectedResponse() {
        return expectedResponse;
    }
    public void setExpectedResponse(String expectedResponse) {
        this.expectedResponse = expectedResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: checkout [this](https://www.java67.com/2016/10/3-ways-to-convert-string-to-json-object-in-java.html)

Comment: Try this one https://dzone.com/articles/converting-json-to-pojos-using-java

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with the help of Jackson:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(source);

    List<MessageDetails> list = Arrays.asList(mapper.treeToValue(node, MessageDetails[].class));
    for (MessageDetails messageDetail : list) {
        System.out.println(messageDetail.getExpectedInput() + ": " + messageDetail.getExpectedResponse());
    }
```